# JQuery Modify a cloned variable (for good)

Tags: jquery, servlets

I know there's many question regarding this subject, however, none of them has worked for me in this particular case.

I'm sending the content of a div as a parameter using ajax. When I say "the content", I mean the html code, which is basically a table with some rows and columns. This code is saved as an html file afterwards in order to generate a PDF file.

Everything works fine so far. My problem is that before I submit this html code, I need to change the src value of 3 images, however, after trying too many options, these changes are never made.

Here's the relevant code:

```
        var exportContents = $('#theResults').find("#reportContent").clone();

        //find the images which src need to be replaced
        $(exportContents).find('.dynImg').each(function(i, obj) {

        var saveAsName = new Date().valueOf() + ".png";

        saveAsName = "../tmpFiles/" + saveAsName;

        $( "input[name=elReporte]" ).val($(this).attr("src"));
        $( "input[name=theFileName]" ).val(saveAsName);
        var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
        theImgData = $("#justForPDFs").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../SaveImgServlet',
            type: 'GET',
            data: theImgData,
            success: function(data){
                $(exportContents).find("#" + currentId).attr("src", saveAsName);
                console.log($(exportContents).find("#" + currentId).attr("src"));

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
        });
```

In these lines I'm changing the desired values, and the console.log shows the correct value:

```
$(exportContents).find("#" + currentId).attr("src", saveAsName);
alert($(exportContents).find("#" + currentId).attr("src"));
```

However, when I submit the variable "exportContents" (after all this) those changes are not there, the src of all of these 3 images remains the same, even if the console.log said otherwise. It seems like "exportContents" variable remains intact. Is there any other way to modify this variable (for good)?

*By the way, although it's not relevant for my question, what the ajax call does is submitting the image urls/names (because they were generated on the fly and don't "exist") to a servlet who will create an actual image and save it. All of this works fine.*

Finally, after all this, the variable "exportContents" is submitted like this:

```
$( "input[name=elReporte]" ).val(exportContents.html());
theData = $("#justForPDFs").serialize();
$.ajax({
.
.//it does more stuff
.
.
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: try putting `async:false` in your ajax requests. async calls in a loop are usually messed up. try waiting for the completion of a single request before sending the other

Comment: WOW!! thanks a lot!!!!, this actually did the trick!!. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Glad it helped,  posted the answer ..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `async:false` in your ajax requests:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '../SaveImgServlet',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: theImgData,
            success: function(data){
                $(exportContents).find("#" + currentId).attr("src", saveAsName);
                console.log($(exportContents).find("#" + currentId).attr("src"));

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
        });
```

This would force the completion of an ajax request before sending another (since this all happening in a loop).

Hope this would help.